# Inline command to knit a chunk

Tags: r, knitr, knitr-spin

The `knitr::read_chunk` function is great for referencing chunks in documents. For example, given an annotated R script:

```
# test.R

## ---- scatter ----------
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)
plot(y ~ x, pch = 19)

## ---- hists ----------
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
hist(x)
hist(y)
```

...I can then reference chunks in a document:

```
# main.Rnw

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
<<setup>>=
library(knitr)
read_chunk("test.R")
@

\begin{figure}
<<scatter>>=
@
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
<<hists>>=
@
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

My questions is: Is there a way to do this inline? I'm looking for a way to do something like:

```
\begin{figure}
    \Sexpr{knit_chunk("scatter")}
\end{figure}
```

...or perhaps something like...

```
\Sexpr{"<<scatter>>"}
```

...which will have the same exact effect as:

```
\begin{figure}
<<scatter>>=
@
\end{figure}
```

It doesn't have to be `knitr` -- perhaps this is something that can be accomplished with `bookdown` text references?

---

**BONUS**: It would be even more awesome if I could set the chunk options in the R script as well. I know that `knitr::spin` (and `knitr::spin_child`) let you do something like this:

```
# test.R 

#+ scatter, fig.width = 3, fig.height = 3
plot(y ~ x)
```

It would be awesome if there was analogous syntax for chunk references -- i.e. if this would work:

```
# test.R

## ---- scatter, fig.width = 3, --------
plot(y ~ x)
```

Alternatively, perhaps the solution to this is to somehow `knitr::spin/knitr::spin_child`, but only on specific chunks?